# Change values in array in android

Tags: android, arrays

I have tow arrays I want when I click on Governorates_nameedt (EditText) show me Governorates_names in AlertDialog and depending in the value I chose the values in state_names Arrays.asList is changed  when I run my code I get an error in `.create().show();` in state_nameedt (EditText).

My code

```
  Governorates_names = Arrays.asList("Ad Dakhiliyah"
                ,"Ad Dhahirah"
                ,"Al Batinah North"
                ,"Al Batinah South"
                ,"Al Buraimi"
                ,"Al Wusta"
                ,"Ash Sharqiyah North"
                ,"Ash Sharqiyah South"
                ,"Dhofar"
                ,"Muscat"
                ,"Musandam");
        if( String.valueOf(Governorates_nameedt.getText().toString()).equals("Ad Dakhiliyah"))
            state_names = Arrays.asList("Nizwa","Samail","Bahla","Al Hamra","Manah","Izki","Adam"  );

        else if( String.valueOf(Governorates_nameedt.getText().toString()).equals("Ad Dhahirah"))
            state_names = Arrays.asList("Ibri","Yanqul","Dhank");

        else if( String.valueOf(Governorates_nameedt.getText().toString()).equals("Al Batinah North")){
            state_names = Arrays.asList("Sohar","Shinas","Liwa","Saham","Al Khaburah","Suwayq");

        }else if( String.valueOf(Governorates_nameedt.getText().toString()).equals("Al Batinah South")){
            state_names = Arrays.asList("Nakhal","Wadi Al Maawil","Al Musanaah","Barka","Rustaq");

        }else if( String.valueOf(Governorates_nameedt.getText().toString()).equals("Al Buraimi")){
            state_names = Arrays.asList("Al Buraimi","Mahdah","Al Sinas");

        }else if( String.valueOf(Governorates_nameedt.getText().toString()).equals("Al Wusta")){
            state_names = Arrays.asList("Haima","Duqm","Mahout","Al Jazur");

        }else if( String.valueOf(Governorates_nameedt.getText().toString()).equals("Ash Sharqiyah North")){
            state_names = Arrays.asList("Ibra","Al-Mudhaibi","Bidiyah","Wadi Bani Khaled","Dema Wa Thaieen","Al Qabil");

        }else if( String.valueOf(Governorates_nameedt.getText().toString()).equals("Ash Sharqiyah South")){
            state_names = Arrays.asList("Masirah","Sur","Jalan Bani Bu Hassan","Jalan Bani Bu Ali","Al Kamil Wal Wafi");

        }else if( String.valueOf(Governorates_nameedt.getText().toString()).equals("Dhofar")){
            state_names = Arrays.asList("Salalah","Taqah","Mirbat","Thumrait","Sadah","Rakhyut","Dhalkut","Muqshin","Shalim and the Hallaniyat Islands","Al-Mazyona");

        }else if(String.valueOf(Governorates_nameedt.getText().toString()).equals("Dhofar")){
            state_names = Arrays.asList("Muttrah","Bawshar","Seeb","Al Amarat","Qurayyat");

        }else if( String.valueOf(Governorates_nameedt.getText().toString()).equals("Musandam")){
            state_names = Arrays.asList("Khasab","Bukha","Daba Al Bayah","Madha");


        }

        final ArrayAdapter<String> Governorates_name_Opt = new ArrayAdapter<>(personal_info.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, Governorates_names);
        final List<String> finalOpt1 = Governorates_names;
        Governorates_nameedt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(personal_info.this)
                        .setTitle("Select ")
                        .setAdapter(Governorates_name_Opt, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Governorates_nameedt.setText(finalOpt1.get(which).toString());
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }).create().show();
            }
        });
        final ArrayAdapter<String> state_name_Opt = new ArrayAdapter<>(personal_info.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, state_names);
        final List<String> finalOpt2 = state_names;
        state_nameedt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(personal_info.this)
                        .setTitle("Select ")
                        .setAdapter(state_name_Opt, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                state_nameedt.setText(finalOpt2.get(which).toString());
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }).create().show();
            }
        });
```

my error

> 05-13 16:42:25.720 8190-8190/com.example.hamdaalissaei.final_flah W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa61a1908)
>   05-13 16:42:25.724 8190-8190/com.example.hamdaalissaei.final_flah E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                           at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)
>                                                                                           at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:462)
>                                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:538)
>                                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:226)
>                                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:257)
>                                                                                           at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:355)
>                                                                                           at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:260)
>                                                                                           at com.example.hamdaalissaei.final_flah.personal_info$6.onClick(personal_info.java:247)
>                                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
>                                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>                                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   05-13 16:42:25.724 466-835/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.hamdaalissaei.final_flah/.personal_info

please help me to solve this problem

Comment: please paste a stack trace

Comment: @Mercato update my question

Answer (score 0):

From your stack trace:

```
8190/com.example.hamdaalissaei.final_flah E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330) at
```

One of your arrays you put as input seems to be null. From your code, `state_names` seems to be the problem. Perhaps none of the `if else` statements are actually working. Try putting

```
else if( String.valueOf(Governorates_nameedt.getText().toString()).equals("Musandam")){
        state_names = Arrays.asList("Khasab","Bukha","Daba Al Bayah","Madha");
    } else {
        state_names = new List<String>();
}
```

Since what the `ArrayAdapter` does is try to find out the size of the array from the array you entered, and it seems that `state_names` is null.

EDIT: state_names seems to be decided on the value of the `EditText` Governorates_nameedt. `EditText` is not a magical thing where every time it is edited it will call the `if else` loop you created. To do that, add a TextWatcher:

```
Governorates_nameedt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            //Put your if else loop HERE
        }
    });
```

When you first run the code before the user puts anything in, just initiate `state_names` to a new `List<String>()` first to prevent the `NullPointerError`

Comment: yes now it show me empty list ...How I can show state_names items!!?